# Bertini-type theorem in positive characteristic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, smoothness

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a morphism of finite type of irreducible schemes over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$. Assume that $Y$ is non-singular. Let $x \in X$ be a closed point and $T_xf:T_xX \to T_{f(x)}Y$ the induced linear map. Then, Proposition III.$10.6$ of Hartshorne's "Algebraic geometry" implies that *for a general $x \in X$*, $\dim \mathrm{Im}(f) \le \mathrm{rk}(T_xf)$ (with notations same as in Hartshorne).

Suppose now that we consider the same setup except that the algebraically closed field in the beginning is of positive characteristic. My question: Is there any known condition on $f$, other than smoothness, under which the above inequality still holds true? Any reference/hint will be most welcome.

Comment: This is not correct and am sure not what Hartshorne says. As I said earlier, have you tried the map $\mathbb{A}^1$ to itself, given by $x\mapsto x^2$ at the origin?

Comment: @Mohan : May be I am wrong, but isn't in this case $T_0 f:T_0 \mathbb{A}^1 \to T_0 \mathbb{A}^1$ takes $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}$ to $2X\frac{\partial }{\partial X}$, where $X$ is the local parameter around $0$ of $\mathbb{A}^1$. Now, $X\frac{\partial }{\partial X}$ is non-zero on \textit{any} open neighbourhood of the origin, hence the rank of the linear tranformation $T_0 f$ is at least $1$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does Hartshorne really use that notation for the stalk of the tangent shead at a point? It is mightily confusing.

Comment: @potentiallydense Sorry. You are right. He does not. I agree that the notation is a bit confusing. The current notation is from a text by Le Potier. The result in Hartshorne states that for a 'general' $x \in X$, the above inequality holds (under the notation that $T_x X$ and $T_{f(x)} Y$ are fibers and not just stalks). I will try to edit the question.

Comment: @Mohan : I have edited the question, hope I have got it right this time.

Comment: @abx: I have edited the question. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @close voters: Granted, this question is not quite research level, but what is "unclear"?  It seems perfectly clear to me what is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

In characteristic $p$, the Frobenius map $\mathbb A^1\to\mathbb A^1$ given by $x\mapsto x^p$ has zero derivative everywhere, but the map itself is surjective (so image has dimension one).

Comment: Is there any known criterion on $f$, other than smooth morphism, under which the inequality does hold true?